# What is Intel xdk local storage size limit

Tags: intel-xdk

I need to develop a mobile application that communicating with rest service. I think that using of intel xdk cross platform may be appopriate for that. I got some informations  via internet investigation about the platform. Then i learnt that local db usage is possible by IndexedDb. But im confused with size limitation of persistent db file. So application may need to db file to use during offline bigger than 10mb. Is it a problem. By the way, offline db contains products with pictures. Im curious about that Is it possible to persist a field with only filepath referenced to mobile storage instead of byte of file? For example is it possible to save picture file which came from service to somewhere belonged to mobile's storage? Finally, can i deploy my program with initial db? Thx, brgds

Answer (score 0):

There are many options for local storage for your app. It is important to understand that an XDK app is a Cordova app. The name XDK refers to the tool, not the runtime environment. Your XDK tool creates Cordova apps.

Try searching for something like "phonegap cordova local storage solutions" for a list of the options available to you when you create a Cordova app.

BTW -- PhoneGap apps are also Cordova apps. :)